# Django AttributeError in vews.py 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'all'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am getting the below error in views.py and I am not able to figure out the reason for it. Please help.

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/tribalrights/

Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    'NoneType' object has no attribute 'all'
Exception Location: /home/gunjan/tribalrights/tr/views.py in home, line 70
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
```

Below is the function which is being called in views.py . Line 70 starts just next line to for declaration.

```
def home(request):
    atrocities = Atrocity.objects.all()
    cities = City.objects.all()
    for atrocity in atrocities:
       #this is line 69.below is line 70. 
       cities = atrocity.location.all()
    return render_to_response('tr/home.html', {
            'cities' : cities,
        })
```

Below in the definitions for City and Atrocity attributes in models.py

```
class Atrocity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    dateTimeOccurred = models.DateTimeField ( null=True, blank=True )
    persons = models.ManyToManyField ( Person, null=True, blank=True )
    atrocityType = models.ForeignKey(AtrocityType)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    location = models.ForeignKey(City, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    district = models.ForeignKey(District)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=10, null=True, blank=True)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=10, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 1):

`atrocity.location` is a `ForeignKey`, so it points to a single `City`. With your current model, you should just use
`city = atrocity.location` to retrieve the single city associated with an `Atrocity`. You use `.all()` on a manager object representing a bunch of objects, such as `City.objects`, but your `location` field is just a single object.

If you want the `Atrocity.location` field to represent many cities, then you can use

```
location = models.ManyToManyField(City)
```

and call `atrocity.location.all()` to get all the location cities for `atrocity`.

Edit: It seems from your code that you might be trying to get a list of all cities which are the location for some `Atrocity`? If that's the case, you could use

```
cities = list(set(map(lambda a: a.location, Atrocity.objects.all()))
```

and pass `cities` into your template. This gets the the `location` of each `Atrocity` object, and combines them into a set to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Location is a foreign key. A foreign key references only one model. Then   your code has no sense because `.all()` method is for query sets. Should be just:

```
cities = atrocity.location
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is wrong. There is a foreign key relationship so, each atrocity is related to only one location. So, you can not use all

Example:

```
#Each Atrocity is related to only one location
city = atrocity.location

#Each can be related to more than one atrocity
atrocities = location.atrocity_set.all()
```

And instead of looping through each Atrocity object to collect the city. It would be more efficient to do it on the database level. You can do a join query between City and Atrocity via this.

```
cities = City.objects.filter(id__in = Atrocity.objects.values_list('location', flat=True))
```